# Subgroups generated by subsets of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let S and T be subsets of a group G. Prove
(a) if S is a subset of T, then < S > ≤ < T >
(b) < S ∩ T > ≤ < S > ∩ < T >

I am very confused with this problem, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), $\langle S \rangle$ is the group generated by elements of $S$. Since every element of $S$ is in $T$ (by $S\subseteq T$), every element of $\langle S \rangle$ can be produced with elements of $T$. Therefore $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup of $\langle T \rangle$.

For part (b), we can employ a similar argument. Recall that $x \in S \cap T \implies x \in S$ and $x \in T$. For an example, consider $G= \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and let $S=\{1 \mod 4\}$ and let $T=\{2 \mod 4\}$. Then $S \cap T = \emptyset$, so $\langle S \cap T \rangle$ is the trivial subgroup, while $\langle S \rangle \cap \langle T \rangle = \langle T \rangle$.